# What does the use of an asterisk (*) mean in a mysql select statement, other than a wildcard?

Tags: mysql, select

I came across a mysql query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
   SUM(some_amount*(some_field!=90)*(some_date < '2011-04-22')) 
 , SUM(some_amount*(some_field =90)*(some_date < '2011-04-22')*(another_field IS NULL))
FROM 
   some_table
```

What does the * mean in the select statement in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `CAST()` is not necessary for boolean-to-integer conversions. Multiplication is used to convert the sum to 0 for unwanted rows (using the fact that boolean `true` can be cast to `1` and `false` to `0`):

```
some_amount*(some_field!=90)*(some_date < '2011-04-22')
```

if `some_field == 90` or `some_date >= '2011-04-22'`, the corresponding term will evaluate to 0, thereby converting the entire expression to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is a multiplication operation.

example 2*3=6

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard multiplication operator,

```
select 2 * 2
```

= 4

:)

Comment: but the only value that is valid to be multiplied by is the some_amount field; the rest seem like conditions--you wouldn't multiply by the some_date field, or by a null field...

Comment: some_date < '2011-04-22'  <--- this is going to evalute to either 0 or 1, and so can be multiplied

Comment: @Marina, Boolean statements evaluate to 1 for true and 0 for false. In fact, true and false are just aliases for 1 and 0.